# Ajax post request keeps on throwing error message

Tags: php, jquery

[UPDATED] Why does this piece of code keeps on falling to the error callback fxn, while also refreshing the page and submitting my form data to the server. When I also try to debug, it keeps on looping in the jquery file for so long, making me tired of pressing F11. :(

```
var ajax_load = {my image html};
var ajax_processor = 'http://localhost/patientcarev1/ajax_processor/save_physical_info';

$("#save2").click(function() {
    var aData = $("#physical-info-form").serialize();
    $("#ajax_load").html(ajax_load);

    $("#ajax_load").html(ajax_load);
        var request = $.ajax({
         type: 'POST',
         url: ajax_processor,
         data: aData
    });
    request.done(function() { alert("success"); });
    request.fail(function() { alert("error"); });
    request.always(function() { alert("complete"); });

});
```

On step-by-step debug it is falling under the success callback fxn, but if not in debug mode it falls into to the fail callback.. this one is giving me a headache :(

Comment: Use the `debugger` keyword to break when you want it to. You can nest it in `if` statements to break under certain conditions. Instead of stepping through relentlessly.

Comment: The fail callback only occurs when the connection fails. For example if the request times out or your internet goes down. Not exceptions. What type of error are you expecting?

Comment: im testing under ideal situation, therefore im not expecting it to have an error. im just using my localhost server and im using on the same pc where my wamp server is installed, i suppose it cant be connection error.

Comment: If you use Google Chrome you can setup XHR/Ajax logging in the DevTools console settings. Use that for debugging to make sure you send what you expect

Comment: You should see the output in console in firefox(firebug) to debug.